# Which version of Matlab Simulink Control System Toolbox include LQR

Tags: matlab, controls, simulink, toolbox

I have tried some matlab version (2011a, 2012b, and 2015a). The 2012b doesn't include the Control System Toolbox inside Simulink Library. The 2011a and 2015a do include the Control System Toolbox inside Simulink Library. But these Control System Toolboxes don't include LQR.

Do you know which version of Matlab that has the LQR in the Simulink Control System Toolbox?
Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

For the MAthworks On-line Documentation, LQR is available in Matlab 2015a. Have a look at [this](http://www.mathworks.com/help/control/ref/lqr.html)

**Edit31.03.2015**

Well, what you can do is build it yourself. just drug and drop the basic blocks to build the [control structure](http://ctms.engin.umich.edu/CTMS/index.php?example=InvertedPendulum&section=ControlStateSpace#6), create a [subsystem](http://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/creating-subsystems.html) and in the [mask](http://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/block-masks.html), you can [initialize](http://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/initialize-mask.html) to to automatically calculate the LQR.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. All version of Matlab includes LQR function. But what I'm finding is not the LQR function, but the LQR module in the Simulink Control System Toolbox Library. I don't want to design and create LQR by coding. With the LQR module in the Control System Toolbox, I can simple drag and drop, then modified the LQR easily.

Answer (score 2):

What you are saying doesn't make sense. There is no such thing (and never has been) as an LQR block. Can you show us which block you're talking about?

You need to compute your LQR controller in MATLAB using functions such as [`lqr`](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/control/ref/lqr.html), which have been part of the Control System Toolbox for ages, and then use the LTI block to include your controller into your Simulink model.

Note: what toolbox is and is not included in a release depends on your license, not on the release. What you are saying about R2012b not including the Control System Toolbox in Simulink doesn't make sense.